# Is the "that" important as in "and that"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

https://www.foxnews.com/politics/trump-mexico-tariffs-escalating-illegal-immigrants-stop

> The Washington Post reported earlier in the day that the Trump
>   administration was considering the move, **and that** it had broad
>   support in the White House --,  although some aides reportedly tried
>   to talk Trump out of it.

I can't feel the difference between with or without the "that". Can that "that" be removed without meaning of the sentence being changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second "that" could be omitted, and the meaning would be unchanged, but only because it would be implied and understood. Consider first a two sentence version:

> The *Post* reported that X. The *Post* also reported that Y.

These parallel sentences can be combined into:

> The *Post* reported that X and that Y.

This can be elided to:

> The *Post* reported that X and Y.

In the final case a "that" before Y is implied.

The original sentence, omitting the 2nd that. and replacing "it" with its referent for clarity, might read:

> The Washington Post reported earlier in the day that the Trump administration was considering the move, and the move had broad support in the White House...

Comment: WOW, you make me clear where "that" comes from. It's a parallel  of " ... day that". I hadn't aware that.

Comment: The template is a bit more complicated here: **They reported that A _was doing_ X, and that it _had_ Y.** You can't just omit _that_ and leave 'it' in place: that would change the sense.

Comment: @Alex_ander how would it change the sense? See the edit to include the modified  sentence. How is the meaning changed from the original?

Comment: With 'it' left in place and 'that' omitted, the last clause would drop out of the reported speech and refer to all the previous: _(The WP said that...), and it [=the fact that the WP said something] had broad support_.

Comment: The second "that" should be included because the clause "that it had broad support ..." is complement of "reported", which occurs considerably earlier in the sentence.